# Spring MVC :- Form Submission (HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.)

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form

There are two forms each having one submit button in my jsp page ... I want to send form 1 to my controller which consists of two images and few form fields.

Controller.java

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/schoolDetails",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getschoolDetails(){

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    School schools=new School();
    Map referenceData = new HashMap();
    referenceData.put("schoolObject", schools);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("schoolDetails", referenceData);    
    return mav;
}



@RequestMapping(value="/addSchoolDetails",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addSchoolDetails(@ModelAttribute("schoolObject") School school,
        @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image,@RequestParam("logo") MultipartFile logo){

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "schoolDetails"; }

    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    CustomUser user=null;
    if (principal instanceof CustomUser) {
    user = ((CustomUser)principal);
    }

    return "schoolDetails"; 
}
```

schoolDetails.jsp

```
 <form:form method="POST" role="form" action="/GenericApp/addSchoolDetails" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="schoolObject">

    <div class="col s3" id="sName">School Name :</div>
     <input  id="form_text" name="schoolname" type="text" placeholder="School Name"/>

    <div class="col s3" id="sName">Email ID :</div>
   <input  id="form_text" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email ID"/>  

    <div class="col s3" id="sName">State :</div>
     <select name="state" id="state_id" >
        <option>State</option>
        <option>Karnataka</option>                                              
     </select>
     <div class="col s12 m4 l4" id="sName">Upload School Logo :</div>
      <input type="file" name="logo" id="fileUpload" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg"/>
                                                                <span class="button teal ">Choose a Image</span>
    <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" type="submit" name="action">Submit</button>
   </form:form>
```

Comment: please put your all jsp code.

Comment: may be they mentioned line number in your error.! so can you please share on which line they are showing this error ?

Comment: @JekinKalariya I have added parts of my jsp page in the post. As soon as i click on submit it shows me "the-request-sent-by-the-client is syntactically incorrect"

Comment: @ojuskulkarni it is not showing any particular line number for the error.its not reaching the controller method.....

Comment: I think you should use `@RequestParam("schoolObject")` instead of `@ModelAttribute(schoolObject)`

Comment: "schoolDetails.jsp" has no input with the name "image".

Answer (score 0):

As your jsp does not contain any tag having name image correct your jsp file by adding tag with name image also , as below

```
<form:form method="POST" role="form" action="/GenericApp/addSchoolDetails" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="schoolObject">

    <div class="col s3" id="sName">School Name :</div>
     <input  id="form_text" name="schoolname" type="text" placeholder="School Name"/>

    <div class="col s3" id="sName">Email ID :</div>
   <input  id="form_text" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email ID"/>  

    <div class="col s3" id="sName">State :</div>
     <select name="state" id="state_id" >
        <option>State</option>
        <option>Karnataka</option>                                              
     </select>
     <div class="col s12 m4 l4" id="sName">Upload School Logo :</div>
      <input type="file" name="logo" id="fileUpload" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg"/>
                                                                <span class="button teal ">Choose a Image</span>
 <input type="file" name="image" id="image" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg"/>
    <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" type="submit" name="action">Submit</button>
   </form:form>
```